# Looking for a regex pattern to match unique words each with exactly 3 unique characters

Tags: regex

Given a multiline input (shorten for the sake of simplicity):

```
abc
aaaa
bcde
acd
abc
abc
xyz
```

I am thinking of a regex pattern that matches unique words (words that occur just once) each consists of exactly 3 unique characters.
The expected output:

```
acd
xyz
```

My failed (or incomplete) attempt:

```
(?xmi)
^
(?:
([a-z]) 
(?!\1)
([a-z])
(?!\1|\2)
([a-z])
)
$
```

that matches

```
abc
acd
abc
abc
xyz
```

where `abc` must be excluded because it occurs more than once.

#### Edit:

I am using c# or dotnet.

Comment: If you're using the i modifier, you don't need both a-z and A-Z

Comment: What language/flavor are you using?

Comment: @InSync, you are perhaps wondering if the engine supports variable-length lookbehinds?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, because with that the solution would be very straight-forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match the following regular expression, with the `g`, `m` and `s` flags set.<sup>1</sup>

```
^((.)(?!\2)(.)(?!\2|\3).$)(?<!^\1$.+)(?!.*^\1$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xH4Wx0/1)

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^            # match the beginning of a line
(            # begin capture group 1
  (.)        # match any character and save to capture group 2
  (?!\2)     # negative lookahead asserts next character is not equal
             # to the content of capture group 2
  (.)        # match any character and save to capture group 3
  (?!\2|\3)  # negative lookahead asserts next character is not equal
             # to the content of capture group 2 or 3
  .          # match any character
  $          # match the end of a line
)            # end capture group 1   
(?<!         # begin negative lookbehind
  ^\1$       # match the contents of capture group 1 on a preceding line
  .+         # match >= 1 characters (.* won't work)
)    
(?!          # begin a negative lookahead
  .*         # match >= 0 characters, including line terminators
  ^\1$       # match a line that equals the contents of capture group 1
)            # end the negative lookahead
```

---

Note that `((.)(?!\2)(.)(?!\2|\3).$)` can be replaced with the following.<sup>2</sup>

```
((?!.?(.).?\2).{3}$)
```

<sup>1. The `g` flag causes the regex engine to matching after the first match. The `m` flag causes `^` and `$` to respectively match the beginning and end of lines (rather than the beginning and end of the string). The `s` ("single-line" or "DOTALL") flag causes a dot to match all characters, including line terminators.</sup>

<sup>2. Thanks to @InSync and @bobblebubble for enlightening me about this trick and to @bobblebubble for a suggestion that simplified my negative lookbehind.</sup>

Comment: I tried a less straight-forward way. Since it isn't better than this simple solution in any way (if not worse), I'm not writing an answer. However, in case someone wants to compare, [here it is](https://regex101.com/r/MXhxuA/2).

Comment: @InSync, that makes my head hurt. I personally would like to see you post that as an answer for educational purposes.

Comment: There is no capture group 2. All groups are named. `s1` and `s2` are filled during the first lookahead, while `u` is filled in the actual loop.

Comment: @InSync, I believe `\2` should be `\1` in `(?<s1>(?<s2>^(?!.?(.).?\2)[a-z]{3}$))`. (Cool trick that I've not seen before.)

Comment: @bobblebubble, I slapped my forehead after seeing your solution. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland At first I thought yours was another concept but then saw it was quite similar to the demo I linked, not worth to write another answer imho. There are certainly many ways to solve it and who comes later can learn from the already provided answers. My demo was something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/wyw7lu/1).

Comment: @bobblebubble, in that case I’ll simplify my lookbehind  along the lines of what you wrote.